# Justify statement about linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have to justify the following statement:

> **Statement:** “Let $T$ be the linear transformation from $\Bbb R^n$to the $\Bbb R-$ vector space $\mathcal M (\Bbb R,\Bbb R)$ given by $T{(e_i)}=sin(ix)$ and extended linearly. Here $\{e_1,e_2,...e_n\}$ is the standard basis for $\Bbb R^n$”

I don't understand what I need to justify here. Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: The statement (as it is currently given) is just the definition of $T$, so there is nothing to justify. What is the context of this question?

Answer (score 2):

You should justify the fact that T is a linear transformation.
Try showing that for each $u,v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and for each constant $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, $T(u+\alpha v) = T(u)+\alpha T(v)$

Comment: Thank you. and what its mean by $T{(e_i)}=sin(ix)$ and extended linearly

Comment: It means that for each other vector in V, you can describe T as a transformation that hold $T(\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i e_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i T(e_i)$. Note that for each vector you assign a function. (If I understood correctly the statement).

Comment: I have to disagree with this answer: Nowhere in the quoted text is it indicated that the linearity of $T$ should be checked. As $T$ is defined via linear extension this also makes little sense.

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Yes it seemes quite absurd. It seems like there is a problem in the question. But as far as I know the only thing you can justify in the given statement is that T is linear.

Comment: My problem is the same.I could not find out what to justify